# Switching graphics with DRI_PRIME doesn't work; creates zombies (16.04 lts)

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a notebook Lenovo E450 with a switchable graphics. That notebook is certified Ubuntu notebook [according to this site](https://certification.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201411-16166/), so I thought it would work, and in general it does.

However, the notebook has a switchable graphics (AMD+intel), and I cannot get switching to work.

I am finding some obsolete guides from 2012 etc, but I don't want to try those (new Ubuntu doesn't work with proprietary AMD drivers anyway).

I have tried the `DRI_PRIME` method. That is:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep 'VGA\|ATI'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics [8086:1616] (rev 09)
05:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Topaz XT [Radeon R7 M260/M265] [1002:6900]

$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x67 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 5 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x4, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 1 name:TOPAZ @ pci:0000:05:00.0

$ xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink 0 1

$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)

$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer" 
# ...nothing happens...
```

When I run the last command, the command never finished. It seems to be unkillable; ctrl-c, sigterm, sigkill doesn't seem to kill the process, it lingers in `htop` with `Z` status. Interestingly, sometimes, computer crashes after a while (but that happened only once).

When I try to shut down the computer (after running the glxinfo with DRI_PRIME), the shutdown never finishes, and I have to turn off the computer "the hard way" by holding the power button.

When I try the glxinfo with DRI_PRIME, this is immediately displayed in `dmesg`

```
[11966.544102] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[11966.780647] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 14 usecs
[11968.629805] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 1 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11968.835788] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 2 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11969.040749] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 3 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11969.246077] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 4 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11969.451829] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 5 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11969.656722] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 6 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11969.863568] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 7 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11970.068579] [drm:gfx_v8_0_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 8 test failed (scratch(0xC040)=0xCAFEDEAD)
[11970.170712] [drm:sdma_v2_4_ring_test_ring [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu: ring 9 test failed (0xCAFEDEAD)
[11970.170722] [drm:amdgpu_resume [amdgpu]] *ERROR* resume of IP block <sdma_v2_4> failed -22
[11970.170730] [drm:amdgpu_resume_kms [amdgpu]] *ERROR* amdgpu_resume failed (-22).
```

When I boot into windows, the graphics works great and I can easily switch.

Where is the problem?

For completeness, this is my kernel version

```
$ uname -a
Linux karelb 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Well. Now I tried to install "amd pro" drivers. That got the computer to unusable state with a menu where I cannot select anything, because I don't see a mouse. I am thinking of installing Fedora instead.

Answer (score 0):

Edit2: Installing new kernel, 4.10, fixed the issue!

---

Old answer (with more experiments)

Installing LXLE - a distro, based on Lubuntu, based on Ubuntu - seems to fix the issue. I still see the drm errors, but the graphics setting work.

I am not sure, however, how well do other programs play with esoteric distros like LXLE.

(installing the amdgpu pro didn't work for me ; quite the opposite, it made ubuntu stop displaying anything)

Edit: I take it back. After I made `apt-get update` etc, the issue returns back, with exactly the same symptoms, with LXLE. So it is *not* a Unity issue, it's something with perhaps the drivers.